# Use static IP on home network else use DHCP

Tags: windows, dhcp, static-ip

How can I setup Windows (10) so that it has a static IP address on my home network and otherwise use DHCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting to the Internet using a router, you should be able to log into the router's management interface to set up DHCP reservation to hand out your computer the same IP address each time you connect.  You would need the MAC address of your computer to do this, and then you can select the IP address you want your computer to have.

You computer would still be set to DHCP, but when it "talks" to your network asking for an IP address, the DHCP reservation you set up would assign your computer that specific IP address you have set it to give you.